# systemctl Exec format error when trying to run service

Tags: linux, systemctl

Currently I wanted to run my dedicated server on my vps. When I run system `systemctl start csgo.service` it gives me error `Load: error (Reason: Exec format error)` when I run `systemctl status csgo.service` it gives me `/lib/systemd/system/csgo.service:12: Executable path is not absolute: killall -TERM srcds_linux`. Below are the service file that I am trying to run, am I making any mistake since it says format error?

```
[Unit]
Description=CSGO Server
[Service]
Type=simple
User=steam
Group=steam
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
ExecStart=/home/steam/steamcmd/csgo/srcds_run -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 -tickrate 128 +mapgroup mg_active +map de_dust2 +sv_setsteamaccount GsltKeyHere -net_port_try 1 
ExecStop=killall -TERM srcds_linux
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My dedicated server files are inside /home/steam/steamcmd/csgo

Comment: What is `srcds_run`? Script? Executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the manual on unit files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> Note that shell command lines are not directly supported. If shell command lines are to be used, they need to be passed explicitly to a shell implementation of some kind.
>
> Example: `ExecStart=sh -c 'dmesg | tac'`

You'll need to either use `sh` like that or figure out the actual path to your `killall` executable, e.g.

```
[Unit]
ExecStop=sh -c 'killall -TERM srcds_linux'
```

or

```
[Unit]
ExecStop=/sbin/killall -TERM srcds_linux
```

As an aside, that's not the best of `ExecStop` commands; it'll ruthlessly kill *all* `srcds_linux` executables, no matter if they're related to this service or not. Having no `ExecStop` command will have systemd terminate the service by itself:

> Note that it is usually not sufficient to specify a command for this setting that only asks the service to terminate (for example, by queuing some form of termination signal for it), but does not wait for it to do so. Since the remaining processes of the services are killed according to KillMode= and KillSignal= as described above immediately after the command exited, this may not result in a clean stop. The specified command should hence be a synchronous operation, not an asynchronous one.

Comment: The srcds_linux is located in /home/steam/steamcmd/csgo/ aswell, how do I killall with the actual path?

Comment: Just get rid of the `ExecStop=` line, as said you don't generally need it. If you find that `systemctl stop` does not kill the server, you may need to change the `Type=` to something else such as `forking`, depending.

Comment: Yeah I removed the ExecStop before got your answer and the service start running normally, its just I am afraid that without ExecStop something will break. In this case is it okay if I dont use ExecStop?

Comment: Things shouldn't break. Following https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html , it looks like Systemd's default behavior is to send a SIGTERM to the service anyway, so you should be good.

Comment: I'm not sure I have the time for tutoring. Just ask questions on Stack Overflow, people in general will probably help you.